# How to solve PHPickerViewControllerDelegate Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain issues?

Tags: ios, swift, photo-gallery, phpickerviewcontroller

I have a problem choosing multiple images from the photo gallery using PhotoUI.

If I pick 6 photos in UICollectionView it's showing 5 photos.

Logs:

> Filename: IMG_0001
> File Address: <PUPhotosFileProviderItemProvider: 0x6000038b5c00> {types = (
> "public.jpeg"
> )}
> 2023-08-21 11:18:11.204644+0600 PhotoCollection[66458:2314832] [claims] Upload preparation for claim 1BD1CC9C-9E04-4269-ABC8-5AC861F202E3 completed with error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “version=1&uuid=CC95F08C-88C3-4012-9D6D-64A413D254B3&mode=compatible.jpeg” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Users/macbook/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/276CD0A1-6FD0-4F01-ADD7-ED84023C8482/data/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/1B7CC31D-6A9C-4C80-B329-B7E6C132CC81/File%20Provider%20Storage/photospicker/version=1&uuid=CC95F08C-88C3-4012-9D6D-64A413D254B3&mode=compatible.jpeg, NSFilePath=/Users/macbook/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/276CD0A1-6FD0-4F01-ADD7-ED84023C8482/data/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/1B7CC31D-6A9C-4C80-B329-B7E6C132CC81/File Provider Storage/photospicker/version=1&uuid=CC95F08C-88C3-4012-9D6D-64A413D254B3&mode=compatible.jpeg, NSUnderlyingError=0x600001830d20 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
> Filename: IMG_0002
> File Address: <PUPhotosFileProviderItemProvider: 0x6000038b5800> {types = (
> "public.jpeg"
> )}
> Filename: IMG_0003
> File Address: <PUPhotosFileProviderItemProvider: 0x6000038b5780> {types = (
> "public.jpeg"
> )}
> Filename: IMG_0004
> File Address: <PUPhotosFileProviderItemProvider: 0x6000038b5980> {types = (
> "public.jpeg"
> )}
> Filename: IMG_0005
> File Address: <PUPhotosFileProviderItemProvider: 0x6000038b5680> {types = (
> "public.jpeg"
> )}

Codes:

```
import UIKit
import PhotosUI

class HomeVC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var addFilesBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var fileViewCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    private let cellIdentifier: String = "FilesViewCollectionViewCell"
    
    var importedMedia: [UIImage] = []
    var totalSelectedItems: Int = 0
    var progressLabel: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        fileViewCollectionView.delegate = self
        fileViewCollectionView.dataSource = self
        
        self.fileViewCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "FilesViewCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
        
        progressLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 30))
        let leftBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: progressLabel)
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [leftBarButton]
        progressLabel.isHidden = true // Hide initially
    }
    
    // MARK: - Function
    // Update progress label's text
    func updateProgressLabel(_ text: String) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.progressLabel.isHidden = false
            self.progressLabel.text = text
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
    
    // Hide progress label
    func hideProgressLabel() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.progressLabel.isHidden = true
            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = nil
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - IBAction
    @IBAction func addFileBarButtonItemAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        var configuration = PHPickerConfiguration()
        configuration.selectionLimit = 0
        
        let picker = PHPickerViewController(configuration: configuration)
        picker.delegate = self
        present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate
extension HomeVC: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource  {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return importedMedia.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? FilesViewCollectionViewCell else {
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }
        
        cell.filePhotoView.image = importedMedia[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}


// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
extension HomeVC: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.1, y: 0.1)
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0.8, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            cell.transform = .identity
        }, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        
        let width = (fileViewCollectionView.frame.size.width / 4) - 1
        let height = (fileViewCollectionView.frame.size.height / 8) - 1
        return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    }
}

// MARK: - PHPickerViewControllerDelegate
extension HomeVC: PHPickerViewControllerDelegate {
    func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
        dismiss(animated: true)

        for result in results {
            result.itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { object, error in
                if let image = object as? UIImage {
                    self.importedMedia.append(image)

                    if let url = result.itemProvider.suggestedName {
                        print("Filename: \(url)")
                        print("File Address: \(result.itemProvider)")
                    }
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.fileViewCollectionView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am working on the Photo Editor app. Try Pick and Show multiple image or videos in UICollectionView
if I pick 6 photos in UICollectionView it's showing 5 photo.

Comment: 2023-08-21 11:18:11.204644+0600 PhotoCollection[66458:2314832] [claims] Upload preparation for claim 1BD1CC9C-9E04-4269-ABC8-5AC861F202E3 completed with error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “version=1&uuid=CC95F08C-88C3-4012-9D6D-64A413D254B3&mode=compatible.jpeg” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file."

Comment: Are these the 6 standard photos that appears in the simulator's Photos app? If so then ignore the error. There's a bad photo in the simulator. I've been seeing this for quite some time. Avoid the bad photo or test on a real device.